# analysing CODE COVERAGE in SONAR 2.6

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I am using sonar 2.6 with maven 3
I am using the default corbetura plugin for code coverage of my project, but it always shows 0% coverage, although I have written junit test cases using the junit-4.9b2.jar

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.niit.karan</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataBlast</artifactId>
  <name>DataBlast</name>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <build>

<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory> 
<outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory> 

    <plugins>     
<plugin> 
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
     <configuration> 
        <source>1.6</source> 
        <target>1.6</target> 
        <excludes> 
            <exclude>**/*.*</exclude> 
        </excludes> 
    </configuration> 
</plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>

        <forkMode>once</forkMode>

          <instrumentation>
            <ignores>
              <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
              </ignores>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com/example/dullcode/**/*.class</exclude>
              <exclude>com/example/**/*Test.class</exclude>
            </excludes>

          </instrumentation>
        </configuration>

    <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>


  <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0-beta-2</version>
          <configuration>
              <timeout>3600000</timeout> 
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>true</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
  </properties>
</project>
```

And this is the test case I have written just to check the plugin:

```
package test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestCalc extends TestCase{

    Calc calc = new Calc();
    public void testSum(){
        assertTrue(3 == calc.sum(1, 2));
        assertTrue(4 == calc.sum(2, 2));
    }
}
```

Someone please help considering I am a very new user of sonar.. Thanks in advance

Comment: without telling what **exactly** you have already tried or a snippet out of your `pom.xml`, it's hard to help you. please provide more information.

Comment: Sonar uses its own cobertura plugin.  You could post the relevant section of sonar log where the plugin is invoked - if at all

Comment: i ve included the snippets pls help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the same problem before. In my case, it because as Surefire plugin property set wrong:

Maven project always use Surefire Plugin during the test phase of the build lifecycle to execute unit tests. Check your pom.xml if there has test configuration of Surefire. Set the  and  to "false", if they set as "true", Sonar won't compile and run your unit test cases, then there's always 0% coverage:

```
<plugin>                    
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>             
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>              
<version>2.9</version>              
<configuration>             
    <includes>              
        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>       
    </includes>         
    <parallel>methods</parallel>            
    <threadCount>10</threadCount>           
    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> 
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>        
    <skip>false</skip>          
</configuration>                
</plugin>
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The maven-compiler-plugin was configured to skip all source code, including tests. Remove the <excludes> session of plugin configuration, in order that Maven works properly, compiling your source code and tests.